# Why does System.IO.Directory.GetFiles does not have a List(Of String) return overload?

Tags: .net, vb.net, list

I have only found overloads that return an array of strings.
Is there a specific reason why there is no `List(Of String)`?

I have to write

```
Dim nNewStringArray() As String
ReDim nNewStringArray(0)
nNewStringArray = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(uInitDir)
```

instead of being able to just write

```
Dim nNewListOfString As New List(Of String) = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(uInitDir)
```

I feel that `Redim` is a bit old school.

Comment: You can create a `List<string>` from an array. `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("").ToList();`

Comment: It dates from .NET 1.0, it did not yet support generic types.  Use Directory.EnumerateFiles(uInitDir).ToList() instead.  And don't use Redim, that's pointless.

Comment: I'm not sure why you feel the need to call `ReDim`. Just calling `Dim nNewStringArray = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(uInitDir)` works just fine (with a string array being returned). If you want a List just add a `.ToList()` to the end. Also, your proposed line of code creates a `List(Of String)` and then immediately throws it away because it gets replaced with the return value of the `GetFiles` call.

Comment: @HansPassant Doesn't using .ToList() force immediate evaluation of the .EnumerateFiles, thus collapsing it to be the same as .GetFiles?

Comment: ToList causes problemes because you can't call Dim sDirs As New List(Of String) = modIO.GetSubDirsRecursively("e:\company\taxes\taxes_2015"). And If I don't use "New", the initial directory is nothing, and recursive calls will fail. However, since there seems to be actually no overloads with a List(Of String), I have to work my way around it.

Comment: @Andrew - Not the same, there is no extra array.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 3 reasons (in no particular order):

1. When the method was developed there were no generics, and thus no `List<T>`.  So `string[]` was the best strongly-typed option available at the time.
2. You can't overload methods by return type, so it would have to either be called something like `GetListOfFiles()` (bad) or be a breaking change (very bad)
3. it's just as easy to do:

   ```
   Dim nNewListOfString As New List(Of String) (System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(uInitDir))
   ```

Plus you don't *need* to `ReDim` your array as mentioned in the comments to your question.  You can just do:

```
Dim nNewStringArray() As String
nNewStringArray = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(uInitDir)
```

or just

```
Dim nNewStringArray() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(uInitDir)
```

if you prefer.  The only reason I would turn the results into a `List` is if I were going to add items to it.  Pretty much anything else can be done with an array.

Comment: Just a  quick question, please: Dim nNewListOfString As New List(Of String) (System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(uInitDir)) Why is there no = sign???

Comment: You can call a constructor [directly in a declaration statement in VB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77s47661.aspx)